# why do we use java files without main ? What purposes does it meet ? How useful it is .?

Tags: java, file, program-entry-point

I am new to java programming and i just came across to a java program composed of many files and only one of the file had a main function while others did not. I didn't really understood that why don't we have a main function in every java file.

Comment: What do you think a `main` method is used for?

Comment: FOR calling a function mainly

Comment: By definition *it's the entry point for your application and will subsequently invoke all the other methods required by your program.*

Comment: Not every room in your house needs a front door!

Answer (score 2):

Not every file needs a "main" function. For example, you may want to import a file with specific function or class. In this case (a java file without a "main" function), the java file simply represents a chunk of code, which is added to your program. So it doesn't need a separate "main" function, if you already have one.

Answer (score 0):

Every Java program must have an entry point, and that entry point must have a certain signature. Which, as you have noticed, is  `public static void main(String[] args)`

After that, the class that is the entry point can create instances of other classes and/or invoke their methods, or invoke static class-level methods. It is not necessary for those classes to have an entry point, because the program is already running (executing your code) in the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

You'll notice that a common error novice (and sometimes even seasoned) programmers make is trying to run a program for which the runtime environment cannot find an entry point. E.g., [Eclipse: Java, no main method found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696351/eclipse-java-no-main-method-found) (in this example, the problem was that the OP had the wrong method signature). The runtime has to find something to, well, RUN.

If your code is going to be run by some other code (e.g., you are developing a library or an API that contains functionality that will be used as *part* of another application) it may not be necessary for you to have a main method. If you look through the .jar files of some of the standard libraries using your IDE, you should discover that very few of them have classes with a main method - this is because they are not intended to be run alone, but rather in the context of another application.

Answer (score 0):

In java, `main()` is an entry point to a program/application. Sometimes in a application we just need only one entry point to start the program and from this point other necessary code are used.

But not all application necessarily need an `main()`  method - like web application or java applet where a container initiate the application/program.

Answer (score 0):

The `public void main(String args[])` method in java is the entry point to the program. If it is run directly, it will start from the main method. However, not every class that you might make in Java is an acceptable entry point. In fact, in many applications, you should have exactly one `main` method. There is generally not too much need for more. Some java libraries has no main method anywhere at all. This code is generally designed so that it can be used by other java code, and often has no sensible way to run itself. It's not designed to do that. It is designed to help other programs that do.

What classes without a `main` method are used for, is a) to provide functionality for other java programs (dependancies for instance), b) to provide additional functionality to the program that is invoked through the `main` method.

Here is a couple example files that illustrate the second.

MainExample.java

```
public class MainExample{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        OtherClass other = new OtherClass()
        other.doExpensiveComputation1();
        other.doExpensiveComputation2();
    }
}
```

OtherClass.java

```
public class OtherClass{
    public void doExpensiveComputation1(){
        //do stuff here
    }
    public void doExpensiveComputation2(){
        //do other stuff here
    }
}
```

Now, you might be asking, "couldn't I just write those methods inside the main class?". In some cases the answer might be yes, but for more complex code, it generally isn't. In some cases it will be impractical simply because it clutters up the main class too much to keep track of. It is much easier to keep track of code that keeps its classes in different files.

Answer (score 0):

Execution of Java program always starts from Main method.Class having main method is the entry point for the program and further from there you can get the rest of the desired functionality.

If You want you can have main method in each java file, which will behave as multiple entry points for your program.